# Forma de un JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Para explicar mejor mi problema tengo este JSON:

```
{
"Person": [
    {
        "Id":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Extra":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Personal":{
            "Name":"Mario"
        }   
    },
     {
        "Id":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Extra":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Personal":{
            "Name":"Mario"
        }   
    }
    ] 
}
```

Yo necesito que un JSON tenga varias "Person" como algo asi:

```
{
"Person": [
    {
        "Id":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Extra":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Personal":{
            "Name":"Mario"
        }   
    },
     {
        "Id":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Extra":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Personal":{
            "Name":"Mario"
        }   
    }
    ],

{
"Person": [
    {
        "Id":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Extra":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Personal":{
            "Name":"Mario"
        }   
    },
     {
        "Id":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Extra":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Personal":{
            "Name":"Mario"
        }   
    }
    ] 
}
}
```

Pero al parecer no es tan sencillo como ponerle solo una coma... alguien podria por favor darme un ejemplo y explicarme como se haria en esos casos?

Gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu JSON está mal estructurado, por lo que se puede ver tu objeto `Person` tiene un array de objetos. en tu forma de intentar aplicarlo, agregas un `Person` dentro de tu `Person` raiz dejando el objeto algo así:

```
Person{
    [ {Objeto identificador},{Objeto identificador} ],
    Person { ... }
}
```

Lo que puedes hacer es un array de Person desde el comienzo de tu JSON, quedando algo así (Nota como el JSON comienza como array y el siguiente `Person` se agrega al cerrar el primer `Person`):

```
[{
    "Person": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Type": 1,
        "Extra": [{
            "Number": 88888888,
            "Code": 506
        }],
        "Personal": {
            "Name": "Mario"
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Type": 1,
        "Extra": [{
            "Number": 88888888,
            "Code": 506
        }],
        "Personal": {
            "Name": "Mario"
        }
    }]
},
{
    "Person": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Type": 1,
        "Extra": [{
            "Number": 88888888,
            "Code": 506
        }],
        "Personal": {
            "Name": "Mario"
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Type": 1,
        "Extra": [{
            "Number": 88888888,
            "Code": 506
        }],
        "Personal": {
            "Name": "Mario"
        }
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Me ayudo mucho tu explicacion! Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Te explico primero como es que funcionan los JSON.

Dentro del formato de intercambio de datos JSON existen dos estructuras principales: listas/arreglos, y objetos.

La listas o arreglos están compuestas/os por diferentes objetos. Y los objetos almacenan los pares compuestos por llave/valor para definir información dentro de ellos.

Ahora si. Teniendo en cuenta la información anterior, si lo que quieres es difinir diferentes objetos de tipo `person` lo que tienes que hacer es definir todos esas personas dentro de una lista/arreglo. De esa manera podrás acceder a cada persona mediante su indice (así es como se manejan las listas/arreglos; el indice comienza a partir del número 0).

¿Cómo quedaría la estructura? Bueno, esta va a cambiar de acuerdo a la información que deseas manejar, pero teniendo en cuenta las estructuras que colocaste como ejemplo, lo más adecuado sería considerar estructuras con la siguiente forma:

```
[
    {
        "Id":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Extra":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Personal":{
            "Name":"Mario"
        }   
    },
    {
        "Id":2, 
        "Type":1,
        "Extra":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Personal":{
            "Name": "Otro Mario"
        }   
    }
]
```

Observa como dentro de la lista/arreglo `[]` se colocan todos los objetos `{}`, que para este caso en específico representan personas.

Por último, si de verdad quieres asignar un nombre al arreglo, puedes declarar la estructura JSON de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "Persons": [
    {
      "Extra": [
        {
          "Code": 506, 
          "Number": 88888888
        }
      ], 
      "Id": 1, 
      "Personal": {
        "Name": "Mario"
      }, 
      "Type": 1
    }, 
    {
      "Extra": [
        {
          "Code": 506, 
          "Number": 88888888
        }
      ], 
      "Id": 1, 
      "Personal": {
        "Name": "Mario"
      }, 
      "Type": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: MAESTRO! Muchas gracias por la explicacion! Soy nuevo en esto y de verdad necesito entregar eso pero no solo queria saber la solucion sino tambien el porque y como funciona y lo hiciste a la perfeccion! Me quedo sumamente claro!!

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que lo que quieres es algo como esto:

```
{
    "Persons": [{
        "Person": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Extra": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Personal": {
                "Name": "Mario"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "Person": {
            "Id": 2,
            "Type": 2,
            "Extra": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Personal": {
                "Name": "Carla"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Puedes probar tu JSON en [esta](https://jsonlint.com/) página